How to make canonical urls work as intended using NextJS + react-i18next localization?
Im working on a website that I have made using NextJs 14.2.3. I have localization support using react-i18next. I use Vercel for hosting my project.
I am having some issues in regards to getting the correct canonical url generated by latest NextJs metadata conventions, while using react-i18next for localization in my project.
When testing out on localhost I get the intended behaviour where the canonical link for e.g. my main page on my website points to 'https://mywebsite.dk' while switching to english points to 'https://mywebsite.dk/en'.
But when I test this on a Vercel deployment the same main page in danish default language points to 'https://mywebsite.dk/da', while the english version points correctly to 'https://mywebsite.dk/en'. In this case the danish one is not expected while the english canonical url is correct
I know the react-router-i18n is used behind the hood of react-i18next, and that the defaultLocale is used to remove the language prefix in the url if the default locale is selected as language. Thus I assume that the best approach would be to make the non language prefixed danish url the canonical one for danish language selection.
I am so confused at the issue where canonical link points to '/da' is only happening in production and not development on localhost.
Can anybody help me make my default language canonical url point to the default website url with no language prefix? Or a better alternative?
i18nConfig.js:
const i18nConfig = {
  locales: [
    'da',
    'en',
    // 'de'
  ],
  defaultLocale: 'da'
}

module.exports = i18nConfig;

i18n.js (might not be relevant):
import { createInstance } from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next/initReactI18next';
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';
import i18nConfig from '@/i18nConfig';

export default async function initTranslations(
  locale,
  namespaces,
  i18nInstance,
  resources
) {
  i18nInstance = i18nInstance || createInstance();

  i18nInstance.use(initReactI18next);

  if (!resources) {
    i18nInstance.use(
      resourcesToBackend(
        (language, namespace) =>
          import(`@/locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`)
      )
    );
  }

  await i18nInstance.init({
    lng: locale,
    resources,
    fallbackLng: i18nConfig.defaultLocale,
    supportedLngs: i18nConfig.locales,
    defaultNS: namespaces[0],
    fallbackNS: namespaces[0],
    ns: namespaces,
    preload: resources ? [] : i18nConfig.locales
  });

  return {
    i18n: i18nInstance,
    resources: i18nInstance.services.resourceStore.data,
    t: i18nInstance.t
  };
}

middleware.js (might not be relevant):
import { i18nRouter } from 'next-i18n-router';
import i18nConfig from './i18nConfig';

export function middleware(request) {
  return i18nRouter(request, i18nConfig);
}

// applies this middleware only to files in the app directory
export const config = {
  matcher: '/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)'
};

main page.jsx (but all other pages have same setup for canonical urls):
export const metadata = {
  metadataBase: new URL("https://mywebsite.dk"),
  alternates: {
    canonical: './',
  },
}

EDIT 1 - After receiving initial answer
I will try to express myself a bit more clear with an example considering my main page and my 'kontakt' page:

My main page (default language danish) canonical link (this works locally but NOT in production): 'https://mywebsite.dk'
Production canonical url result: 'https://mywebsite.dk/da'

My main page with english selected canonical link (this works both locally and in production): 'https://mywebsite.dk/en'

A sub page (default language danish) canonical link (works locally but not in production): 'https://mywebsite.dk/kontakt'
Production canonical url result: 'https://mywebsite.dk/da/kontakt'

Same sub page with english selected canonical link (this works both locally and in production): 'https://mywebsite.dk/en/kontakt'


EDIT 2
I forgot to mention that i am using the App router for my project.
Also, I have tried changing the canonical: './' to canonical: '/'. This results in all pages not considering the language specific prefix. It solves the defaultLocale url now having correct canonical "https://mywebsite.dk" for main page & "https://mywebsite.dk/kontakt" for contact page but all non defaultLocale urls are not including /lang
I keep getting back to the fact that the canonical links seems (to me) perfect when testing locally on localhost with ./:

Page: "https://mypage.dk" canonical: "https://mypage.dk"
Page: "https://mypage.dk/en" canonical: "https://mypage.dk/en"
Page: "https://mypage.dk/kontakt" canonical: "https://mypage.dk/kontakt"
Page: "https://mypage.dk/en/kontakt" canonical: "https://mypage.dk/en/kontakt"

But when deploying to production on Vercel and testing live with ./:

Page: "https://mypage.dk" canonical: "**https://mypage.dk/da**"
Page: "https://mypage.dk/en" canonical: "https://mypage.dk/en"
Page: "https://mypage.dk/kontakt" canonical: "**https://mypage.dk/da/kontakt**"
Page: "https://mypage.dk/en/kontakt" canonical: "https://mypage.dk/en/kontakt"

I feel like the above happening on localhost is the intended behaviour. But maybe im too unexperienced in how to use canonical urls? The highlighed ones are the ones I think is an issue (because we are redirected to url without lang always when using defaultLocale)
If in fact it is common practice to do something like the following, accepting the latter of what is coming, then please let me know:
Use "https://mywebsite.dk/da" and "https://mywebsite.dk/en as two canonicals while always being redirected to non-canonical "https://mywebsite.dk" when visiting "https://mywebsite.dk/da" or changing from a non-danish language to danish language.
If you need further details I will happily provide. Hope someone might be able to help me!
Kind regards
Morten

You can't have same canonical for different page.
Example:
Use canonical www.site.com/about for about page even with different languages like www.site.com/about-us, www.site.com/about-ar etc.
But don't use canonical www.site.com/about for different page like contact page, home, page etc.
Page with different purposes should have their own canonical.
In your case your error caused by this code:
alternates: {
canonical: './',
},

I will try to express myself a bit more clear:
My main page (default language danish) canonical link (this works locally but NOT in production):
https://mywebsite.dk
My main page with english selected canonical link (this works both locally and in production):
https://mywebsite.dk/en
A sub page (default language danish) canonical link (works locally but not in production):
https://mywebsite.dk/kontakt
Same sub page with english selected canonical link (this works both locally and in production):
https://mywebsite.dk/en/kontakt

So my issue is with the danish default language that the canonical link for e.g main page should be 'https://mywebsite.dk' but in production ends up like 'https://mywebsite.com/da'. Hope this clarifies a bit

My intention is that all pages as they have unique content (including language specific pages as everything on page is translated into selected language) should have their own canonical link

I have updated my question with correctly formatted clarifications.

I just read your answer a couple of times.. If i understand you correctly you want all languages to share the same canonical url?
I guess I could use https://site.dk/about for e.g. about page but then the language specific version of that page would not be canonical as they all point to whats currently used for default danish language url. I have been researching and it's my impression that its perfectly fine and even better to have language specific canonical urls for the same page if the page is entirely translated into another language upon changing the language (which it is in my case).

Another solution that I was not sure would be a good idea was to live with the fact that https://site.dk will not be canonical while https://site.dk/da and https://site.dk/en would both be canonical. But then after redirect to defaultLocale (the danish language) would always result ending up on a non-canonical page as https://site.dk/da redirects to https://site.dk. If this is a viable solution - do let me know!
